# looking to replicate something like

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

i recently went on tumbler and seen a javascript/ jQuery/ God knows, script an example here...

http://cl.vc/Beta/Tumbler/

when you type in the URL box it adds text behind it that the user can not edit but can see. i have a project that would fit perfect with it so i want to know how to do it...

thanks for reading
regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `<span>` positioned after the `<input>`.
This `<span>` is positioned next to the `<input>` field with a z-index lower than the blue part of the site. Use 'inspect element' and you'll find the surprisingly easy structure it uses.

Comment: Indeed, seems to use the input as a binding mechanism, but uses spans for display purposes.

Comment: @Brad_Christie - Thanks... so when the is no text in the field `<span>` is `-2 z-index` then when the is text it goes `1 z-index`? i yes i will do i mock up now.